# Facebook integartion context null error

Tags: facebook-login

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null
>                                                                                            at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:76)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:594)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.(AppEventsLogger.java:757)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.(AppEventsLogger.java:732)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.java:400)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.logButtonCreated(FacebookButtonBase.java:225)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.onAttachedToWindow(FacebookButtonBase.java:136)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.onAttachedToWindow(LoginButton.java:452)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: i am getting same error, my code was working, it created error now.

Comment: hello arth i am resolve this error by using old facebook sdk version